# Running a Client-Server Chat program

Tags: java, client-server, chat

This is one of the most common application scenario that can be found all over the net. and I'm not asking any questions about the java codes that I did because I was successful in running it on my laptop where both the client and server part of the .java file resides. Rather I have had problem getting it to work in between two computers. I tried establishing physical connection using cross-over cable to connect two computers, and did a test to see if file transfers successfully and it did, however, keeping one Server part of the .java file in one computer and client part in the other, I tried to run the server first and then the client but it got a "access denied" error.

For reference here's my two .java files:

```
/* ChatClient.java */
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class ChatClient {
private static int port = 5000; /* port to connect to */
private static String host = "localhost"; /* host to connect to (server's IP)*/
private static BufferedReader stdIn;
private static String nick;
/**
* Read in a nickname from stdin and attempt to authenticate with the
* server by sending a NICK command to @out. If the response from @in
* is not equal to "OK" go bacl and read a nickname again
*/
private static String getNick(BufferedReader in,
PrintWriter out) throws IOException {

System.out.print("Enter your nick: ");
String msg = stdIn.readLine();
out.println("NICK " + msg);
String serverResponse = in.readLine();
if ("SERVER: OK".equals(serverResponse)) return msg;
System.out.println(serverResponse);
return getNick(in, out);
}
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
Socket server = null;
try {
server = new Socket(host, port);
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
System.err.println(e);
System.exit(1);
}
stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
/* obtain an output stream to the server... */
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(server.getOutputStream(), true);
/* ... and an input stream */
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
server.getInputStream()));
nick = getNick(in, out);
/* create a thread to asyncronously read messages from the server */
ServerConn sc = new ServerConn(server);
Thread t = new Thread(sc);
t.start();
String msg;
/* loop reading messages from stdin and sending them to the server */
while ((msg = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
out.println(msg);
}
}
}
class ServerConn implements Runnable {
private BufferedReader in = null;
public ServerConn(Socket server) throws IOException {
/* obtain an input stream from the server */
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
server.getInputStream()));
}
public void run() {
String msg;
try {
/* loop reading messages from the server and show them
* on stdout */
while ((msg = in.readLine()) != null) {
System.out.println(msg);
}
} catch (IOException e) {
System.err.println(e);
}
}
}
```

and here's the ChatServer.java:

```
    /* ChatServer.java */
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Hashtable;

public class ChatServer {

private static int port = 5000; /* port to listen on */

public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
{
    ServerSocket server = null;

    try {
            server = new ServerSocket(port); /* start listening on the port */

        } catch (IOException e) {

System.err.println("Could not listen on port: " + port);
System.err.println(e);
System.exit(1);
}

Socket client = null;

while(true) {
try {

client = server.accept();

} catch (IOException e) {

System.err.println("Accept failed.");
System.err.println(e);
System.exit(1);
}

/* start a new thread to handle this client */
Thread t = new Thread(new ClientConn(client));
t.start();
}
}
}


class ChatServerProtocol {

private String nick;
private ClientConn conn;

/* a hash table from user nicks to the corresponding connections */
private static Hashtable<String, ClientConn> nicks =
new Hashtable<String, ClientConn>();

private static final String msg_OK = "OK";
private static final String msg_NICK_IN_USE = "NICK IN USE";
private static final String msg_SPECIFY_NICK = "SPECIFY NICK";
private static final String msg_INVALID = "INVALID COMMAND";
private static final String msg_SEND_FAILED = "FAILED TO SEND";

/**
* Adds a nick to the hash table
* returns false if the nick is already in the table, true otherwise
*/

private static boolean add_nick(String nick, ClientConn c) {

if (nicks.containsKey(nick)) {
return false;
} else {
nicks.put(nick, c);
return true;

}
}

public ChatServerProtocol(ClientConn c) {
nick = null;
conn = c;
}
private void log(String msg) {
System.err.println(msg);
}
public boolean isAuthenticated() {
return ! (nick == null);
}
/**
* Implements the authentication protocol.
* This consists of checking that the message starts with the NICK command
* and that the nick following it is not already in use.
* returns:
* msg_OK if authenticated
* msg_NICK_IN_USE if the specified nick is already in use
* msg_SPECIFY_NICK if the message does not start with the NICK command
*/
private String authenticate(String msg) {
if(msg.startsWith("NICK")) {
String tryNick = msg.substring(5);
if(add_nick(tryNick, this.conn)) {
log("Nick " + tryNick + " joined.");
this.nick = tryNick;
return msg_OK;
} else {
return msg_NICK_IN_USE;
}
} else {
return msg_SPECIFY_NICK;
}
}
/**
* Send a message to another user.
* @recepient contains the recepient's nick
* @msg contains the message to send
* return true if the nick is registered in the hash, false otherwise
*/
private boolean sendMsg(String recipient, String msg) {
if (nicks.containsKey(recipient)) {
ClientConn c = nicks.get(recipient);
c.sendMsg(nick + ": " + msg);
return true;
} else {
return false;
}
}
/**
* Process a message coming from the client
*/
public String process(String msg) {
if (!isAuthenticated())
return authenticate(msg);
String[] msg_parts = msg.split(" ", 3);
String msg_type = msg_parts[0];
if(msg_type.equals("MSG")) {
if(msg_parts.length < 3) return msg_INVALID;
if(sendMsg(msg_parts[1], msg_parts[2])) return msg_OK;
else return msg_SEND_FAILED;
} else {
return msg_INVALID;
}
}
}

class ClientConn implements Runnable {

private Socket client;
private BufferedReader in = null;
private PrintWriter out = null;

ClientConn(Socket client) {

this.client = client;

try {
/* obtain an input stream to this client ... */
in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
client.getInputStream()));
/* ... and an output stream to the same client */
out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
} catch (IOException e) {
System.err.println(e);
return;
}
}

public void run() {
String msg, response;
ChatServerProtocol protocol = new ChatServerProtocol(this);
try {
/* loop reading lines from the client which are processed
* according to our protocol and the resulting response is
* sent back to the client */
while ((msg = in.readLine()) != null) {
response = protocol.process(msg);
out.println("SERVER: " + response);
}
} catch (IOException e) {
System.err.println(e);
}
}

public void sendMsg(String msg) {
out.println(msg);
}
}
```

Now, what should I do in order to run this two files from two computers given that I have the physical connection(TCP/IP) setup already??

Thanks in advance... :)

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like it's quite possibly a firewall problem. Have you tried opening a hole in your firewall for port 1001?

Comment: I did guessed that and added the port 1001 via my computer which has windows XP OS, however, due to lack of knowledge/experience in windows 7, which one was my friends computer, I could not find a way to add a port on his, Do I have to do it on both computers and how about the ip address, if u please explain the procedures that would be great help...thanks

Comment: You should also use a port above 1024. Since those are usually used for system processes and well known services.

Comment: @Niaz: You'll have to do it on each computer which is acting as a server, at least. It's not clear what you mean by "how about the IP address" though. I've just seen that you've hardcoded "localhost" into your client code though... that's clearly not going to work when you want to connect to another computer.

Comment: @PeterT, thanks for the info as I'm just a beginner that helps a lot. @Jon Skeet : The code posted here was the version when I tried it on my local computer, that is why I mentioned about the "IP address" and not sure about it where should I put the client's IP and the server's IP?

Comment: @Niaz: In the ChatClient, where you've got "localhost", you should have the server IP address. Note that you've actually posted ChatClient twice, so we can't see the ChatServer code...

Comment: @Jon: OOPS!!! my bad, let me edit that quickly, sorry for the inconvenience, see this is what happens when somebody's newbie..LOL

Comment: @jon:Changed it and also changed the port number to 5000 as suggested by PeterT

Comment: @Niaz: So having changed the port, opened the firewall, changed the client to mention the host to connect to... is it working?

Comment: @Jon: Unfortunately, I'm now at my home and can't test it out since there's no other pc to connect to, however, I really appreciate your help and will try it out as soon as I get my friend's PC. I will keep the hierarchy described by you in mind and see if I can get to work. One thing, I'm not sure though, as mentioned earlier, I could not find a way to get the option to add port in the firewall on windows 7(my friend's PC)? "changed the client to mention the host to connect to" - did u mean to put server's IP address in the ChatClient.java??

Comment: @jon: Once again, thanks a lot for all you help and sure, after I test it out, I'll post the updates on that and thanks to everyone for their helps

Comment: @Niaz: Just pressing the Windows key and typing "firewall" will probably get you to the right menu. And yes, I mean you need to put the server's IP address in ChatClient.java.

Comment: @Jon:Thanks for the clarifications. And I am sorry if I did not clear myself when I said that I could not find a way to add port on windows 7, in fact, I found firewall, but on windows 7, it only allows to add programs not port...anyways, I think I can work the other way around; like making mine(windows xp) as the server so that I can add client port through firewall and let my friend be the client.

Answer (score 0):

Have you also looked at your `java.policy` and make sure that it is configured to allow local codebase to open sockets?

Comment: No I haven't and not sure how to do that

Comment: could you please explain on this 'java.policy' ?

Comment: sorry, i was offline for a while. Look in your `JRE/lib/security/java.policy` you need to ensure that you have permissions to listen on that port (by default it only allows ports over 1024 I think) and also need to ensure you have connect permissions to for your code base. This link is for JDK 1.4 but still applies: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/PolicyFiles.html

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in comment, you should not use port < 1025 for you applications, since they are always used in deamon processes. However you should test your program like this

1) if you get connection refused then you should check the exception properly, whether client program takes time before generating exception ( that mean request is going to server and then it's giving connection refused), in that case you should try java.policy 
put following in a file named java.policy

grant {
    permission java.net.SocketPermission "*:1024-65535",
        "connect,accept";

    permission java.net.SocketPermission "*:80", "connect";
    permission java.io.FilePermission "*", "read,write,delete";

    permission java.security.SecurityPermission "*";
};
while compiling use this flag `-Djava.security.policy=java.policy`
more-over you should also try -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=IP, where IP is clien-ip for client.java and server-ip for server.java


2) if you are immediately getting exception at client side then your request is not going outside your pc, so client has some problem.

check the exception properly and post them over here.

3) though i've not got access denied error, but it seems to have port problem that might be solved using policy or port>1024.

post what are you getting now.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed information, unfortunately, I'm at my home and there's no other pc that i can get connected to, as soon as I can, I will do what you mentioned and post the updates here. BTW, "-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=IP" -- you've mentioned IP is client-ip and server-ip, so do i put -Djava.rmi.client.hostname=IP for ChatClient.java??

Comment: One more thing, in this program, I haven't used the rmi so do i have to use it and then perform the compilation instructions u said about??

Comment: oh, if you get connection refused then you should use something similar to rmi ( don't know what ), but you are not using rmi so you should not.

Comment: These are really good stuffs that I'm learning here, and that I would not be learning just by reading books and doing codes in java, thanks all of you for giving these new materials to me for strengthening my knowledge